# General topology book recommendation for advanced probability theory

Tags: probability, general-topology, book-recommendation

I would like to know if anyone could suggest a general topology book for a deeper understanding of probability at advanced level.

Comment: How about Real Analysis and Probability by Dudley? I haven't read it myself, but it seems to have few chapters about topology as well.

Comment: What is your actual goal? The vast majority of topology is completely useless for understanding probability. Are you reading a book on probability theory that requires some topology background?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk my goal is to try to master topology before studying advanced probability.

Comment: "Master topology" is too broad a goal -- no one on earth has mastered all of topology, there is just too much of it for any one person to learn. We can certainly recommend introductory texts on point-set topology, differential topology, etc., but as I said previously most of this knowledge would not be very relevant to probability theory. It would help to know specifically what sorts of "advanced probability" topics you'd like to study, so that we can direct you to resources that will actually be helpful towards your long-term goals.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that plenty of expert professional probabilists don't know particularly much topology. If your ultimate goal is to learn probability, it's not clear that starting with topology is going to be especially useful. Obviously you may want to study topology for its own sake!